# Is there a way to formulate a peak finding function which also detects plateaus?

Tags: c++, algorithm

The code below is what i've written which works with most cases but the task is as follows:

With an input int vector, peaks and the positions of the peaks need to be found, some examples and conditions include:

```
arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 5, 1, 0 } 
         Then the peak is at position 3 with a value of 5
arr[] = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 1} 
         If the array plateaus, the peak is the first position of the plateau so in this case, its 2 at 
         position 1
arr[] = { 1 , 2, 2, 2,3)
         This array does not plateau or have a peak so the return value is {}
```

I don't know what went wrong with my code because it works with the examples i mentioned above but since this is a codewars problem, they test it with huge data inputs which is where it fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct PeakData
{
    vector<int> pos, peaks;
};

PeakData pick_peaks(vector<int> v)
{
    PeakData result;
    int max, position, j;
    for (int i = 1; i < int(v.size()) - 1; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        if (v[i - 1] < v[i] && v[i] == v[i + 1])
        {
            while(v[i] == v[j]){
                j++;
                cout<<v[j]<<endl;
            }
            cout<<v[j]<<endl;
            if(v[j] < v[i]){
            position = i;
            max = v[i];
            result.pos.push_back(position);
            result.peaks.push_back(max);
            } else continue;
        }
        if (v[i - 1] < v[i] && v[i + 1] < v[i])
        {
            position = i;
            max = v[i];
            result.pos.push_back(position);
            result.peaks.push_back(max);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{

    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3};
    pick_peaks(v);
    for (int i = 0; i < pick_peaks(v).peaks.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Peak: " << pick_peaks(v).peaks[i] << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pick_peaks(v).pos.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Position: " << pick_peaks(v).pos[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the output you are getting for mentioned test cases?

Comment: @NitinSinghal For the specific tests i mentioned, the outputs were as expects so as i said i said post but this is a codewars problem and they test this algorithm with huge arrays and it fails then.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by _"I don't know what went wrong with my code"_

Comment: @paddy Sorry about that, my code does not work with huge inputs at the input of the function, for the specific conditions i mentioned, it works perfectly but not with huge vectors with lots of data.

Comment: One thing I see is your plateau test `while(v[i] == v[j])` is going to run off the end of the array if given a test case like `{1, 2, 2, 2, 2}`

Comment: @paddy thats one of the bugs that my brain froze on and cant think of a solution :(

Comment: Really?  What do you think `j++;` does?

Comment: You can make a check inside ```while loop``` for ```j``` if it reaches to end or not

Comment: @NitinSinghal @paddy i got confused with the i and j sorry but the only solution i can think of is ```j--;``` when the while loop breaks but idk if that would be the best solution

Comment: `while(v[i] == v[j] && j < int(v.size()) - 1)` perhaps.

Comment: @paddy Your solution and my ```j--``` solution both work. Thank you so much

Comment: No, I don't believe you.  `j--` is _not_ a fix for your inner loop having unbounded array traversal.

Comment: Some other things I would point out.  This whole approach to the problem is over-complicated.  All you really need to do is visit each element once and remember the position of a candidate peak.  That is: the index of any value that is greater than the previous.  When you encounter a value that is less than the candidate, then you store the candidate index as a peak.  You do not need to also store the value, since that can be obtained from the index anyway.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but function "pick_peaks" should take a (const) reference as argument. Right now a needless copy of the input vector is created and destroyed every time you call the function.